# Sending messages to specific clients

Tags: java

I need to send messages to a specific client from a java server. For this I'll need to keep track of name of each client. How do I get the name of each client?(Get host name is not I want). And using that name I should be able to send data to that specific client.

Comment: Please add more information on what you have tried ? What components/frameworks are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your server is serving the port 6789... then the server is waiting infitely for client and is someone come and connects to the server a socket is created for the data exchange, the point is: your server comes back and listen again on the port 6789 for another client, and the previous one is getting a port choose for the networking system, that port is unique for that connection session to that client... and of course is the same between both connected sockets...

you can get that number when asking the port, that can works as an id as long as the client is there (so you can see that as some kind of session id)

try with:

```
Socket#getPort();
```

or `Socket#getLocalPort();`

I can not remember well which one a I used

more info is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getPort()) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getLocalPort()).

Comment: This helped. Thank you so much.